# How do DropBox and OneDrive appear as file systems in Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows, filesystems

We have a web app that has a bunch of user files (stored as BLOBs in a database). I want to be able to present them in Windows File Explorer as Dropbox and OneDrive do, as a file system that is not a C: driver and not a \server\share.

How can I do that?

Comment: [Understanding Shell Namespace Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/nse-works).

Comment: That's it - thank you. If you make it an answer, I'll select it.